# How to sub-melt a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

My `df` is made from Excel file but I can't share the file :
`df = pd.read_excel("file", header=None)`

So I made this one that looks like it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['id', 'id1', 'id', 'id2', 'id1', 'id', 'id3', 'id2'], 1: ['col1', '1', 'col1', '4', '6', None, None, None], 2: ['col2', '2', None, None, None, 'col2', None, '8'], 3: ['col3', '3', 'col3', '5', '7', None, None, None]})
print(df)

0     1     2     3
0   id  col1  col2  col3
1  id1     1     2     3
2   id  col1   NaN  col3
3  id2     4   NaN     5
4  id1     6   NaN     7
5   id   NaN  col2   NaN
6  id3   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  id2   NaN     8   NaN
```

I need to iterate over each group of sub dataframes and maybe use `melt` to fix the Excel file.

My expected output is this :

```
id number variable value
id1      1     col1     1
id1      1     col2     2
id1      1     col3     3
id2      2     col1     4
id2      2     col2      
id2      2     col3     5
id1      2     col1     6
id1      2     col2      
id1      2     col3     7
id3      3     col1      
id3      3     col2      
id3      3     col3      
id2      3     col1      
id2      3     col2     8
id2      3     col3
```

I made the code below but some rows shouldn't be there.

```
data = df.groupby(df[0].eq("id").cumsum())
final = []
x = 1
for i, j in data:
    final.append(j.melt(id_vars=0).assign(number=x))
    x = x+1

new_df = pd.concat(final)
print(new_df.head())
     0  variable value  number
0   id         1  col1       1
1  id1         1     1       1
2   id         2  col2       1
3  id1         2     2       1
4   id         3  col3       1
```

Can you guys tell me what am I doing wrong ? Is there another way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and post-process with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
(df.rename(columns={0: 'id'}).melt(id_vars='id', var_name='number')
   .assign(m=lambda d: d['id'].eq('id'),
           variable=lambda d: d['value'].where(d['m'])
                            .groupby(d['m'].cumsum()).ffill()
          )
   .loc[lambda d: ~d.pop('m')]
)
```

Output:

```
     id number value variable
1   id1      1     1     col1
3   id2      1     4     col1
4   id1      1     6     col1
6   id3      1  None      NaN
7   id2      1  None      NaN
9   id1      2     2     col2
11  id2      2  None      NaN
12  id1      2  None      NaN
14  id3      2  None     col2
15  id2      2     8     col2
17  id1      3     3     col3
19  id2      3     5     col3
20  id1      3     7     col3
22  id3      3  None      NaN
23  id2      3  None      NaN
```